# Making a Piecewise Function a Single Function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to turn a piecewise function into one function. For example:

$$\ f(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & \text{if $a≤x<b $} \\ h(x) & \text{if $b≤x≤d$} \end{cases}$$

(Can you use the Heaviside Step Function? $\theta(x))$

Comment: Note that even if you do this (for instance to enter it into certain calculators that don't give direct support for piecewise functions), any actual work you do with it will tend to break it into piecewise functions *anyway*.  (I think laplace transforms are about the only place I see otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\chi_{[a,b)}(x)g(x)+\chi_{[c,d)}(x)h(x),$$ where $\chi_{[a,b)}(x)$ is $1$ if $x\in[a,b)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Okay, thank you...Is X the HSF?@Clayton

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make a pulse with the step function $$\displaylines{
  f(x) = g(x)\left( {\theta (x - a) - \theta (x - b)} \right) \cr 
   + h(x)\left( {\theta (x - b) - \theta (x - d)} \right) \cr} $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the description you gave is already a function.

You could use the Heaviside Step Function, but note that this will define a function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and not just from the intervals $[a,b]\cup[c,d]$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. @konewka