# The derivative of generalized functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let {$x_k$}$_{k\in K}$ be a sequence of real numbers, numbered in ascending order,
$K =$ {$1,..., n$},or $K = \mathbb{N}$, and the sequence {$x_k$}$_{k=1}^{\infty}$ has no accumulation endpoints.

Let the function $f$ be absolutely continuous at each interval $(x_k, x_{k+1})$ and have discontinuities of the first kind at points $x_k$,

$h_k := f (x_k + 0) − f (x_k − 0)$.
Prove that $f'_{general.} = f'_{classic.} + \sum_{k\in K} h_k\delta _{x_k}$.

I don't quite understand how to show it.

Comment: I worked on a similar problem recently. Good question, but since you haven't shown your work, I'm not going to upvote the question. Let's strip off math formalism and consider some step function (go ahead and draw it: visual aid will help you a lot here). Say: we have XOY coordinates and the function is $y=1$ till $x=5$ and is $y=2$ after $x=5$. I.e we have discontinuity at $x=5$. You can represent this function in a single expression using the Heaviside function. Having written down that expression, differentiate it. You'll get Dirac delta at the discontinuity and $f'_{classic}$ elsewhere.

Comment: See my post and the links in it here to understand how to rewrite your function via the Heaviside function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261935/how-to-write-a-formula-for-a-piecewise-function-that-contains-a-single-separate. And see this post to understand how to differentiate it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165666/how-to-differentiate-ft-thetat-the-product-of-a-function-with-the-heavisi?rq=1